# How to specifically/conditionally target Yahoo and AOL within HTML emails for client specific fixes?

Tags: css, conditional-statements, html-email, yahoo, aol

That code should be targeting any Outlook clients that came before '15' and Outlook.com but it doesn't seem to work that well.

```
<!--[if (lte mso 15)|(office365) ]>
<style type="text/css">
.client-fix{ 
  display: none!important;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Anyways what I really need to do be able to target Yahoo and AOL but so far I haven't found any reliable information on how to do so.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some yahoo solutions online, but I haven't gotten them to work. I was able to target AOL by applying a class and selecting it with the following code:

```
.aolReplacedBody .bullet {
        styles here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020, with Yahoo having recently updated their codebase, a new way of targetting AOL & Yahoo together has come about, the trick being to have an uncommon unicode element as the ID so that Yahoo will not filter it out:

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- START force fallback on Yahoo/AOL -->
<style>
    .& #√ .yahooAOLhide {display: none !important;}
    .& #√ .yahooAOLshow {display: block !important;}
</style>
<!-- END force fallback on Yahoo/AOL -->
<table id="√"><tr><td>  
<div class="yahooAOLhide">
    @@@@@@@@
</div>
<div class="yahooAOLshow" style="display: none;mso-hide:all;">
    YAHOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!
</div>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669117/yahoo-mail-css-targeting-2020/60942106#60942106 (Yahoo targetting) because AOL is almost dead, so it's basically about Yahoo targetting.