# Yahoo Mail CSS Targeting 2020

Tags: css, email, html-email

In 2019, email developers used to be able to target yahoo mail's css with the media query below:

```
<body>
<style>
@media screen yahoo {
.class-name {css}
}
</style>
```

My issue is with using web fonts. I need to target font-size for yahoo mail.

Is there a new method for targeting yahoo mail css in 2020?

Thanks

Comment: Hello! Yes, it's the same method as above.

Comment: Why would Yahoo have different font size requirements? It would be the same as many other email clients that also do not support web fonts (most don't)

Comment: From my experience, condensed web fonts need a larger font-size to display properly. A 48px font-size might be great for the web font but because Yahoo Mail doesn't support web fonts, a 48px font-size in Arial is too large. If we can't target yahoo mail css we can't target the font-size to scale it back.

Comment: There are many more email clients that do not support web fonts - Gmail, Outlook, etc. ---- do you want to change your question?

Comment: Hi Nathan, you're right. Gmail and Outlook (unless you're on a mac) do not support web fonts. However, you can target their CSS. We used to be able to target Yahoo Mail CSS. Sorry if the web-font example was confusing. Maybe I should update my question?

Comment: Yes maybe just some more context would be good because normally I would just have a generic fallback -- but in your case you need something specific because you want font-size and perhaps other things changed too.

Comment: Your ultimate goal is to have a different size & font for those email clients that support webfonts. Can you try the other way -- set the default as Arial and the smaller font-size, and, then use client-specific to target those that would support the other font? I.e. targetting apple, samsung, and outlook app?

Comment: That's a great alternative method. I never thought about doing it that way. That makes more sense to me. Would still be nice to be able to target Yahoo Mail css for other cases. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alice Li of Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/interactive-hotspots-in-email-a-step-by-step-guide) has worked out that the new Yahoo filters for 2020 do not filter out weird unicode characters.

However, it appears to capture AOL & Yahoo (I say 'appears' because it comes up intermittently on Litmus previews):

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- START force fallback on Yahoo/AOL -->
<style>
    .& #√ .yahooAOLhide {display: none !important;}
    .& #√ .yahooAOLshow {display: block !important;}
</style>
<!-- END force fallback on Yahoo/AOL -->
<table id="√"><tr><td>  
<div class="yahooAOLhide">
    @@@@@@@@
</div>
<div class="yahooAOLshow" style="display: none;mso-hide:all;">
    YAHOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!
</div>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the `<style>` section must be written in the `<body>` so as to work with the Yahoo app too.

Answer (score 2):

I am using this system to solve this problem. I have just found that with a lot of try/error testing with the Gmail/Yahoo/Outlook and MacMail and this seems to work. The element with the id="yahoo-show" is only visible in Yahoo. However I don't know if it will still work with other less used mailing systems. None of the answers written here seems to work fine for me but this.

```
        @media only screen{
            [id="yahoo-show"]{display:block !important;}
        }

        /* Intended commented line (Otherwise it will appear in both Yahoo and MacMail App) */
        a[id="yahoo-show"]{display:none !important;}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the StackOverFlow, If you want to answer a question. please provide a little bit more detail about your answer. Posting an answer is not enough if you can explain why u think this approach will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
<!-- START force fallback on Yahoo -->
<style>
.& #☃ .yahoohide {display: none !important;}
.& #☃ .yahooshow {display: block !important;}
</style>
<!-- END force fallback on Yahoo -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a hell of a time with my email that worked in all versions of Outlook but was running into issues on Yahoo Mail and AOL Mail. I tried the yahoo media query and could not get it to work, and so I figured I would try `@supports` and it worked.

`@supports` not `(box-sizing:border-box)` has the parameter filtered out and becomes `@supports` not `(_filtered_a)`, thus becoming `true` and then targets the desired elements. My Email on Acid test confirms it works for AOL and I verified it on my test Yahoo account.

Comment: This was my first comment after several years of using this site. The fact that my comment was edited is just absurd. It is _my_ comment. _My_ voice. I will not be contributing again. I imagine you will just be editing this as well.